# Error:(27, 20) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Division

Tags: java

estoy intentando realizar el siguiente programa, es un ejercicio de mi clase de Java el cual se llama uso de la palabra return, quise agregarle una condición pero no salio y el error que salio es el del Titulo me podría alguien por favor decir porque no funciono, se los agradecería enormemente, ya probé varias cosas pero aun así no me funciono. El código es el siguiente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalabraReurnClase_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        Division d = crearObjetoDivision();
        double resultado = d.a / d.b;

        System.out.println("resultado = " + resultado);
    }

    public static Division crearObjetoDivision() {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Valor A = ");
        Double a = Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Valor B = ");
        Double b = Double.parseDouble(entrada.nextLine());

        Division d = new Division(a,b);

        if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
            System.out.println("El valor es cero, por favor introduzca otro diferente de cero");
            return 0;
        }

        //Division d = new Division(a,b);
        return d;
    }

}

class Division {
    double a;
    double b;

    //Creando el constructor
    Division(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que cuando insertas `A=0` y `B=0` entra en la condición y devuelve `0`, el error se lanza en la linea `Division d = crearObjetoDivision();`, ya que no puede convertir un `int` en `Division`.

Aqui está una posible solución en donde se seguirá pidiendo entradas hasta que `A` o `B` sea distinta de `0`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalabraReurnClase_2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        Division d = crearObjetoDivision();
        double resultado = d.a / d.b;

        System.out.println("resultado = " + resultado);
    }

    public static Division crearObjetoDivision() {

        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Valor A = ");
        Double a = entrada.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Valor B = ");
        Double b = entrada.nextDouble();

        while (a == 0 && b == 0) {
            System.out.println("El valor es cero, por favor introduzca otro diferente de cero");
            System.out.println("Valor A = ");
            a = entrada.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Valor B = ");
            b = entrada.nextDouble();
        }

        Division d = new Division(a, b);
        return d;
    }

}

class Division {

    double a;
    double b;

    //Creando el constructor
    Division(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu sugerencia si funciono, te lo agradezco mucho